# How to redirect my web www.myweb.com to www.myweb.com/index.html

Tags: html

I'm trying to redirect my web to index page of my web. If i configure it directly in my admin panel, it don't load css styles and javascripts. I need your help.

Thanks.

Comment: "my admin panel". Uh, which web framework are you using, or which hosting service are you using? Right now, we don't have enough information to actually answer your question.

Comment: Sorry, i use hostalia.com

Comment: In this moment, my web show index of contents (directories, css files, js files and html files)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to try and redirect to `index.html` as the browser will do that for you by default.  You need to fix the issues in the JS and CSS files.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure this question is answered elsewhere, but please specify which admin panel do you refer to.

As a side note, I did this directly from the DNS redirection from the panel of my domain seller. As well, CSS and javascripts should not be disturbed by the redirection, they should load independently. Check that the links to the files (i guess they will be located separately from the html) point to the correct directories first.

Comment: if i redirect my old web to my new web as follow:

www.mynewweb.es --> www.myoldweb.es/index.html

not load css and javascripts. Is there any way to not change all routes of css and javascripts files. 

Sorry, I'm new at this.